# How to Stream a byte array to UI and download it asynchronously in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to send an excel in the form of byte array to UI asynchronously and get the excel downloaded in the UI. 
Can anyone help me how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [StreamingResponseBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/StreamingResponseBody.html)

> A controller method return value type for asynchronous request processing where the application can write directly to the response OutputStream without holding up the Servlet container thread.

(also watch out for the *Note* mentioned in the javadoc!)

For example, if you want to download a CSV with the name "example.csv":

```
@GetMapping("/downloadCsv")
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> downloadCsv() {
  HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
  httpHeaders.setContentType("text/csv");
  httpHeaders.setContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.builder("attachment").filename("example.csv").build());

  return () ->
    new ResponseEntity<>(
      outputStream -> downloadService.downloadCsv(
      "example.csv", 
      outputStream),
      httpHeaders,
      HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

As you did not tell us what UI you are using, I focused on the backend.

Comment: 1st the code is not readable without any formatting and imports, 2nd please update your question with your code. 3rd: What should be asynchronously, the download itself?

Comment: I've already answered your question. I'm not going to re-write your code (assignment?). My example code is very small but complete. It's your job to understand the code, learn from it and apply the lessons learned to your code.